# How to auto-complete url in safari

Tags: safari

Can someone tell me what is the keyboard shortcut for auto completing a URL in the safari address bar?

PS: Like in chrome or Firefox the keyboard shortcut is Control+return, Command+Return.

Comment: if it presents a list of possibles, down arrow.

Comment: Are you saying this is not possible in Safari? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There IS a way - in Safari Version 10.0.3 at least.

Type a slash ("/") after the domain name. As in,

```
semiconducted/<enter>
```

will resolve to www.semiconducted.com

Voila!

Answer (score 4):

When the list of suggestions comes up use the up/down arrow keys to scroll through the options. Press Enter to accept the currently highlighted option.

Comment: My work is such that everyday I visiti new sites, for references and most of them are not so popular enough that Safari can guess. (- 1, That should have been a comment.)

Comment: Why a comment? Safari does not have a shortcut to add ".com". You asked for autocompletion and the answer is OK.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> in Firefox is not really *autocompletion*: it just adds `.com`

From [Keyboard shortcuts - Perform common Firefox tasks quickly: Miscellaneous](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_miscellaneous)

- Complete `.com` Address: <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>return</kbd>
- Complete `.net` Address: <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>return</kbd>
- Complete `.org` Address: <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>return</kbd>

Safari does not offer this feature.

With the down arrow you can choose either

- a suggestion from Google Search
- or an entry from your browsing history and bookmarks

Answer (score 2):

If you start to type anywhere you've ever been [assuming you don't delete your history] it will start to present a list of the most-used/most common possibilities.
Hitting Enter will go to the top hit; otherwise arrow down.

Otherwise, if there's nothing useful in history to auto-complete & you don't step down with the arrow key…

If it thinks it's a url it will automatically try .com first [& also it will test whether www. is needed, though that's less important these days]

If it can't completely figure out that what you're typing is a url it will send it to Google instead.

Based on my previous history, this is what happens as I slowly type 'apple.co.'

**apple** - [I spend a lot of time on Ask Different] ;)

[image]

**apple.c**

[image]

**apple.co.**

[image]

However, if I go off-piste & type something it doesn't have a hit for, like **applez**, it will switch to Google

[image]

*BTW, I have a lot of the 'pretty' icons & helpers switched off, in prefs.*

[image]